# Filter domains by user with SENDMAIL

Tags: domain, sendmail

I administer one mail server that hosts several domains in it. I.E.

- Mail Server: supermailserver.mydomain.com

Hosting mail for domains:

- domain1.com
- domain2.com
- domain3.com
- domain4.com
- domain5.com

I have my user database with OpenLDAP. The server works just fine. There is only one thing I  would like to tweak which is the following:

Right now, if I add a user "username" to OpenLDAP and the CyrusMail backend, then "username" gets mail through the following addresses:

- username@domain1.com
- username@domain2.com
- username@domain3.com
- username@domain4.com
- username@domain5.com

The tweak I would like to make is to allow "username" to get emails only from selected domains. What's the best (and easiest) way to do this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Switch to Postfix? ;-) (seriously though, if at any point it is feasible to switch... Postfix configuration is easier to understand and probably easier to get help with)

Answer (score 1):

We setup explicit entries in virtusertable for domains that we accept mail for:

```
@domain1.com         error: 5.1.1:550 User %1@domain1.com unknown
user1@domain1.com    %1+%2
user2@domain1.com    %1+%2

@domain2.com         error: 5.1.1:550 User %1@domain2.com unknown
user3@domain2.com    %1+%2
user4@domain2.com    %1+%2
```

This forces you to list out every mail address that you accept (which can be interpreted as either bad or good)

Comment: great. is there an easy way to administer that table other tan manually editing the file and restarting sendmail? for example, can I put that info on a MySQL database to build a proper Mail Administration Web Frontend?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you could use the M4 macro FEATURE(`virtusertable',`dbtype') where dbtype can be ldap or dbm as an example to use a database instead of a file.